# MSBUILD - Remove a character from a variable without knowing its position

Tags: msbuild

I read a build number from my TFS Team build which looks like "AB-1.2.3.4-CDE-REV.1". I want to edit this number and remove the last decimal point and make it look like "AB-1.2.3.4-CDE-REV1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you want to manipulate strings in msbuild you're looking to use [Property Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx). In the documentation of those you'll read you can use String functions so next up is figuring out which methods of [System.String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) you need. In this case: LastIndexOf and Remove should do the trick:

```
<!-- BuildNumber property is fetched elsewhere -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildNumber>AB-1.2.3.4-CDE-REV.1</BuildNumber>
</BuildNumber>

<Target Name="ManipulateBuildNumber">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildNumber>$(BuildNumber.Remove($(BuildNumber.LastIndexOf('.')),1))</BuildNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="New build number is $(BuildNumber)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution stijn. It works. I had figured out another lame and crude way of doing it.

```
<BuildNumber>AB-1.2.3.4-CDE-REV.1</BuildNumber>
<Part1>$(BuildNumber.Split('.')[0])</Part1>
<Part2>$(BuildNumber.Split('.')[1])</Part2>
<Part3>$(BuildNumber.Split('.')[2])</Part3>
<Part4>$(BuildNumber.Split('.')[3])</Part4>
<Part5>$(BuildNumber.Split('.')[4])</Part5>
<BuildNumber>$(Part1).$(Part2).$(Part3).$(Part4)$(Part5)</BuildNumber>
```